# Forge Design Automation - Error: AutoCAD Core Console is shut down due to timeout

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am using design automation with AutoCAD.
But I got an error that looks like "timeout"

I don't know what the problem is and how to fix it. Help me, please. Thanks so much.
This is the report of design automation.

```
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Start script phase. 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump. 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Redirect stdout (file:  T:\Aces\Jobs\8ab2b9c2e8c04c6f9e6401a760efc4c3\tmp\accc28282).
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2021 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (S.51.Z.120) 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Execution Path: 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\24.1\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Current Directory: T:\Aces\Jobs\8ab2b9c2e8c04c6f9e6401a760efc4c3 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_8ab2b9c2e8c04c6f9e6401a760efc4c3,userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\8ab2b9c2e8c04c6f9e6401a760efc4c3\userdata.
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] Version Number: S.51.Z.120 (UNICODE) 
[03/10/2023 09:52:07] LogFilePath has been set to the working folder. 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] Regenerating model. 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] AutoCAD menu utilities loaded. 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] Command: 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] Command: 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] Command: 
[03/10/2023 09:52:08] Command: DETECTIONCMD 
[03/10/2023 09:53:08] Error: AutoCAD Core Console is shutdown due to timeout. 
[03/10/2023 09:53:08] End script phase.
[03/10/2023 09:53:08] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job. 
[03/10/2023 09:53:08] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

Comment: the timeout means there is no response from AcadCAD during the running. But the information you provided is not enough for a diagnosis. Could you post more about scritp/addin you are running? You can send more information to aps.help@autodesk.com.

Comment: The problem is that your DETECTIONCMD is too silent. Make sure that it writes something to the command line at least once every minute so that we know it is making progress. Design Automation will consider your command "hung"/"deadlocked" if it makes no output/progress message on the command line for 60s.